# Ajax-call refreshes page

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webforms

I have a list of elements in a gridview and I need to delete them with web-method, update gridview and don't reload the whole page. But after every call the page reloads.

My button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server"  CssClass="btn btn-default" Text="Delete a row" OnClientClick="DeleteRecord() return false;" />
```

JS-script for it:

```
function DeleteRecord() {
    var inputData = jsTextBox();
    if (confirm('Are you certain you want to delete this record?')) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "SubjectTable.aspx/DeleteRecord",
            data: inputData,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#<%=gdViewSubj.ClientID%>').empty();
                if (data.d.length > 0) {
                    fillGrid(data);
                }
            },
            failure: function (data) {
                alert(data.d);
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
}
function fillGrid(data) {
    $('#<%=gdViewSubj.ClientID%>').append("<tr><th>SUBJ_ID</th><th>SUBJ_NAME</th><th>HOUR</th><th>SEMESTER</th></tr>");
    for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
        $('#<%=gdViewSubj.ClientID%>').append("<tr><td>" +
                    data.d[i].SUBJ_ID + "</td> <td>" +
                    data.d[i].SUBJ_NAME + "</td> <td>" +
                    data.d[i].HOUR + "</td> <td>" +
                    data.d[i].SEMESTER + "</td></tr>");
    }
}
```

So when I check the script step by step, I see that everything's fine, gridview is cleared and then filled without deleted row. But after end of the script page reloads and I see the old row. If I close page and open it again, then I get an updated table.

What is the root of this issue and how to fix it?

Comment: Could it be that you're simply missing a `;` before the `return` here `OnClientClick="DeleteRecord() return false;`?

Comment: Oh, what a studip typo. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you are missing a `;` after your `DeleteRecord()` on the onClientClick event.

But also If you not using the built in features of the asp:Button. why not just use a regular button. that way the asp.net framework doesnt add any call back functions to it. If you add the `runat="server"` tag you can still modify the button on the server side. try changing it to this

`<button ID="btnDelete" runat="server"  Class="btn btn-default"  onclick="DeleteRecord(); return false;" >Delete a row</button>`

Comment: Yes, the issue was in this typo. That's why I don't like js :)

Answer (score 0):

Your onclick function:

> ```
> DeleteRecord() return false;
> ```

will throw an error:

> Unexpected token return

You need to end your first statement with a semi-colon.

```
DeleteRecord(); return false;
```